# Get samples that contain 0 value and still plot all the values

Tags: r, plot

I wanted to plot only the samples that, in the whole given X-range they have at least a 0 value, but still be able to plot, to see if the Y=0 is only in a point or continuous along the X.

Until now I was trying it by filtering the data like this:

```
data_0values <- data[data$value %in% c(0),]
```

That gives me the amount of samples that have 0, but when plotting, it only plots across the 0, so I cannot know which one has other values in that X-range.

Which would be the best way of doing that?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Provide example data with the output of `dput(dff)`, it makes it possible for others to reproduce your issue. Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
  data[which(data$value >= 0,]
```

Comment: Please don't use answers as comments.

Comment: It would be better to try to get the reputation points first.